# I'm annoyed with asp .net mvc action links? Is there something better in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After almost 3 years with mvc I'm scratching my head. Is it just me, or does the way we specify links in asp .net mvc suck?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account")

@Html.ActionLink("Australia", "CountryDetail", "Places", new { id = "Australia", filter = "xxx", morejunkvaliablesrepeatedoverandaver = "guuuuuuuuh"}, null)
```

In the previews for mvc 1 we had the funky generic action links which gave us intellisense and compile checking, which I LOVED. I know they removed them because of performance issues and because you could not actually guarantee that the route would resolve all the time... However the default way of doing it just doesn't make me feel safe enough in a big application.

I've also used T4Mvc with MVC2, to be honest, I didn't really like it. It's not part of the Mvc framework and frustrating to develop with especially with source control in big teams and continuous integration builds.

I guess I could also import Mvc Futures and keep using the generic types (it's probably what I'll do).

I'm just about to start a very big project and was wondering what other people are thinking? Is anyone else annoyed with the options or has a new solution?

It seems like ActionLinks are the most basic & frequently used feature. Shouldn't there be a good out of the box solution, we're just about to hit revision 3 of this framework.

Comment: Why not create an alternate helper that behaves the way you want? Better yet, why not pull the generic implementation out of the preview source and get it working with what you're using now?

Answer (score 4):

I disliked this too at start. Tried T4MVC too. Generated proxy classes felt too cumbersome.

Then I realized something.
If Your views and controllers are named and structured obviously, then they like never change.

It's better to make everything easy to follow and understand instead of trying making everything super safe. Understanding [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) is the key.

So I don't care about these "magic strings" anymore.

Comment: It's not even the magic string I care that much about... It's that there's no intellisense for half the coding abd that I have to specify ugly anonymous objects without being shown what parameters my action methods are expecting. It's just ugly to look at too.

Comment: @Jonathon You should embrace "dynamicness". intellisense and strongly typing often enough just provides false feeling of safety for quite high price - unnecessary verboseness in code. play around with Ruby to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use MVC Futures helpers to avoid magic strings in views hoping that some day Microsoft will find some time to incorporate them into the framework.

Comment: Yeah right... just like there will be switch`es on type`s. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at other web frameworks and steal some of their ideas if you like them.

Answer (score 0):

I robbed the HtmlTags library from FubuMVC and use it for generating anything related to HTML. Here's a [post](http://geekswithblogs.net/ryanohs/archive/2010/04/21/a-semantic-model-for-html-tagbuilder-and-htmltags.aspx) I wrote about it. There aren't any generics but at least you don't have to remember all the overloads anymore and it would work well with T4MVC.

```
Html.LinkToAction("Edit").Text("Edit").AddClass("navigation")
```

vs

```
Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", null, new { @class = "navigation" })
```